# Pushing background div down when moving another div on top

Tags: html, css, sass

I am running it situation where i have div which i am position on top of another div with position absolute. I want to move background div down so that it appears after the moving div and
i need to it by applying CSS on moving div only. I can't add CSS to background div because then i will have to add lot more code for complete functionality. Below is simplest form of my code:

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.background-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.moving-div {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">HEADER CONTENT</div>

  <div class="background-div">
    <h2>SUBHEADER CONTENT</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="moving-div">
    Content of moving div<br />Content of moving div
  </div>
</div>
```

So what i want is, "SUBHEADER CONTENT" div should go down the "Content of moving div" by adding css in "moving-div" only.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: .moving-div {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  margin-top: 40px; /* Adjust the margin-top value as needed */
}

Comment: margin-top will move the moving-div down. I want to keep moving-div at same location and SUBHEADER CONTENT div to move down the moving-div.

Comment: .background-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -40px; /* Adjust the margin-top value as needed */
}

Comment: It can be done by adjust margin-top in background-div as you suggested. But as i mentioned, due to limitation i can't add css in background-div. I can only add css in moviing-div.

Comment: .moving-div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 40px; /* Adjust the height to control the space */
}